# Acessar arquivos em C:\\ dando erro: O acesso ao caminho (...) foi negado

Tags: c#, path

Eu estou fazendo um programa em C#, que precisa acessar todos arquivos e pastas do computador. Acontece que quando eu vou acessar uma pasta ou arquivo perto de `C:\`, ele diz esta mensagem:

> O acesso ao caminho 'C:\2953323222e00ecf35c7' foi negado.

Como eu posso acessar todas pastas e arquivos sem dar este problema? Executar como administrador não resolve.

Comment: executando como administrador

Comment: @Rovann Linhalis eu executei como administrador, não resoulveu.

Comment: o que é `2953323222e00ecf35c7` ? uma pasta ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Sim

Comment: possivelmente é uma pasta protegida do sistema operacional, você precisa acessá-la ou pode ignorar ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize a classe [`System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity(v=vs.110).aspx) para pedir acesso como administrador. Aplicações se autenticam para ter permissões de administrador dessa forma, e não apenas sendo executadas como administrador.

O código deve parecer com o seguinte:

```
string user = "X"; // Troque X pelo nome de usuário de um administrador.
System.IO.DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\2953323222e00ecf35c7");
DirectorySecurity ds = new DirectorySecurity();

ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(user, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow));
ds.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, false);
folderInfo.SetAccessControl(ds);
```

Se o código acima não resolver como está, dê uma olhada na documentação para conseguir a exata permissão que precisa.

**Créditos** - peguei o código desta pergunta no SO em inglês:

[Visual Basic .NET Access to the path 'C:\' is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18390625/2263584)